# How to handle selenium exceptions in splinter (python)?

Tags: python, selenium, splinter

Sometimes, when I try to click a button, it's covered by another element and I get a `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException`. It happens rarely and it's not a huge deal, so I would like to ignore it and keep going instead of exiting the script.

I tried

`except selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException as c:`

and

`except ElementClickInterceptedException as c:`

Both throw errors, I'm assuming, because I'm not importing selenium directly, I'm using splinter: `NameError: name 'ElementClickInterceptedException' is not defined`

Example of my code:

```
if browser.is_element_present_by_css('a.User', wait_time=15):
    try:
        browser.find_by_css('a.User').first.click()
    except ElementClickInterceptedException as c:
        pass
```

How do I handle an error selenium throws while using splinter?

Answer (score 1):

Try using javascript to click.

```
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", browser.find_by_css('a.User').first)
```